ZAP user is not loaded in authentication tab
I am useing ZAP 2.15.0 on Windows 10 machine and i need to use a created user for Form-Based-Authentication. i have already created my user as you see in below picture:

However, no user shows up in the Authentication tab:

is it a bug in zap product ? or i forgot to do something beofre ?

The user will not appear in the authentication tab.
What will be shown are the possible username and password parameters.
But those are based on the parameters available, and you have not specified any.
If you add "Login Request POST Data" like aaa=bbb&ccc=ddd then you will see aaa and ccc as available parameters you can choose.
Its worth nothing that we do not expect you to fill this out manually, its better to flag the relevant login request via the relevant right click option.
Also, if you are new to ZAP authentication then you are better off starting here: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/authentication/
